# What is the size of an empty MS Word 2003 (.doc) document?

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-word

I'm trying to troubleshoot a problem Word document which has become blank after editing. 
It's file size is 22.0KB (22,528 bytes).

Is this the same file size of an empty document - i.e. if you open Word 2003 and then save the empty doc?

I only have Office 2007 available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have Word 2003 installed and using Explorer's `Right Click` -> `New` -> `Microsoft Word Document` option I got a file which is 10.5 KB (10,752 bytes)

This creates a copy of the document located at `C:\WINDOWS\ShellNew\WINWORD8.DOC`.

They are "Binary same" as reported by Beyond Compare.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Interesting. If I right-click to get a new Word 2007 doc it is 0 bytes (suggesting it's not actually a Word file at that point but just a placeholder with a .docx extension). Whereas, if I create a new blank .docx from within Word 2007 it is 9.82KB.  
What size do you get if you launch Word 2003 and then save the blank doc?

Comment: @pelms - I get 19.5 KB (19,968 bytes)

Comment: I think the 'ShellNew' file will by definition be the same as the one you get by right-clicking. Is that the same file size as when you start from Word and save a blank doc?

Comment: @pelms - interesting, I did a Beyond Compare (which compares Word Doc contents) on the 2 files and they are content identical

Comment: @Shevek. OK, thanks. Looks like my file might not be completely blank then.

Comment: @pelms: what do you get if you "save as" your new Word 2007 doc in Word 2003 .doc format?

Comment: The differences in size between multiple users for blank documents may have something to do with differing default templates.

Answer (score 2):

Each user can edit their own standard document template, Normal.dot, so there isn't a specific size against which you can compare.  However, 22k is in the ballpark for a typical Microsoft Word 2003 blank document.

Comment: It would be pretty much the default normal.dot

Answer (score 0):

That would also very per user. Some users have extra information such as copyright information which could add to the empty word document's file size.